# Why is $2^{2^{2^n}}$ not equal to $16^n$?

Tags: power-towers

Why is $a^{b^{c^d}}$ not equal to ${(a^{b^c})}^d$ (for positive n)?

For example, WolframAlpha seems to say that $2^{2^{2^n}}$ is not equal to $16^n$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the solution of $2^{2^{2^2}}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340216/what-is-the-solution-of-2222)

Comment: Because the notation `2^2^2^n` is ambiguous (and should be avoided).

Comment: Why would you think it is?

Comment: @Did How is 2^2^2^n ambiguous? It's clearly 2^(2^(2^n))

Comment: The key conception is [operator associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity). Unlike addition and multiplication, exponentiation is right-associative. If you see an expression of the form `a^b^c^d`, the operator should apply from right to left. i.e as it the expression is bracketed with implicit parenthesis `(a^(b^(c^d)))`.

Comment: @Max And what happens if somebody insists that it is "clearly" `((2^2)^2)^n`? You call the Pope for their advice?

Comment: @Max Not every author uses this convention (which seems to be originating from a programming context rather than from mathematics). Hence: ambiguous. Hence: to be avoided.

Comment: @Max, how is this priority rules? Exponentiation has higher priority then exponentiation? This is not a case of $2+2^2$ for priority to decide, this is a question of left/right associativity. I do agree that right associativity is usual here (I've never seen someone treating it as left associative) but this is not obvious, it is a convention (differing from convention for subtraction, for example).

Comment: Also, in Did's favor, try typing `$2^2^2^n$` in MathJax and see what it tells you.

Comment: @Ennar *Proof by MathJax*: A new kind of proof... :-)

Comment: The associativity of exponents is defined by convention.  It is defined this way because the reverse convention proposed in the OP is a waste of space.  We often need to write $a^{(b^c)}$ so it is convenient not to require parentheses.  However $(a^b)^c$ can be written more simply as $a^{bc}$ except in occasional delicate cases with branch cuts.  It's a waste to create a simpler notation for something that is already simple, when it could be serving a much more useful purpose.

Comment: @Ennar Apparently I was wrong. It's like Did is saying - it's common in *some programs (e: not even generally - just the ones I've been working in). I've been kind of stuck with them for a while, so I automatically thought right associativity. My mistake.

Comment: I think the moral of the story here is: if you're in doubt about how others will interpret your order of operations and/or associativity, put in parentheses.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks +1 from me for this moral.

Comment: I am not aware of any person with a mathematical education who does **NOT** think that a power tower is parsed top-down, i.e.
$$a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}.$$ My old pocket calculators didn't do it that way, but those used reverse Polish, when all bets are off anyway. I am surprised that someone well versed in probability would think that  for example
$$e^{-x^2}$$ is ambiguous??? Siding with Max.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is purely a matter of notational convention that $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$ rather than $(a^b)^c$, but it's a convention that makes sense:  There would be no point in using the notation for the second convention, since it would be easier to simply write $a^{bc}$ -- and likewise for $a^{b^{c^d}}$ if the notation meant $a^{b^{c^d}}=(a^{b^c})^d=((a^b)^c)^d=a^{bcd}$.  One reason for adopting it as a convention is that the unambiguous notation

$$a^{\left(b^{\left(c^d\right)}\right)}$$

takes up way more room.

Comment: Practical answer.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is here what you mean by

```
a^b^c
```

For example:
$$
(2^3)^2 = 8^2 = 64 \\
2^{(3^2)} = 2^9 = 512
$$
Or
$$
(2^{(2^2)})^3 = 16^3 = 4096\\
(2^2)^{(2^3)} = 4^8 = 65536
$$
So there is an example with $n=3$.

You want to use paratheses to make it clear what you want to do.

In fact recall the rule that 
$$
(a^b)^c = a^{b\cdot c}
$$

Answer (score 4):

The operation ^ is not associative, i.e. in general $a^{(b^c)}\neq (a^b)^c$. The usual convention is 
$a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$.

Answer (score 4):

The mistake people make usually is they go from down to up rather than coming from up to down.  $${16^n}$$ is nothing but $${(2^n)(2^n)(2^n)(2^n)}$$.

On the other hand, While solving for $$2^{2^{2^n}}$$ You will have to come down by giving the upper powers to the 2's which are lying below.

For example $$2^{2^{2^2}}=(2^{16})$$

If we use your terminology it will be 256 which is false.

Comment: What does "terminology" mean in the last sentence?

Comment: @ErickWong, I just wanted to say that if the OP will use the method he is asking, the answer will be wrong.

Comment: Perhaps "notation" makes more sense in the last line.

Answer (score 4):

Although I think Barry Cipra's answer should be the canonical one, I think there is also an argument against the OP's proposal on typographical grounds: if the intent of $a^{b^c}$ was to convey $(a^b)^c$, then there would be no justification for making the $c$ smaller, since it is then a top-level exponent and not a superscript within a superscript: it should look like ${a^b}^c$ rather than $a^{b^c}$.  The fact that the $c$ is intentionally typeset smaller than $b$ establishes the intent that the $c$ is an exponent within a term that is already in smaller type size, namely the exponent of $a$.

Of course, semantics need not always follow syntactic structure literally.  For instance, there is a practical limit to how small one can make subscripts, so in a tall tower of exponents we might see exponents at different heights with the same type size.  But I can see no reason for exponents at the *same* height to have different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Note: $a^{b^{c^d}} = a^{b^{(c^d)}} \neq {(a^{b^c})}^d$