# Exponents and order of execution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, exponentiation

If presented the following, what order should the parentheses be added?

2^2^2^2

It seems most tools go right to left. Is that correct/expected? I could not find clear information on this.

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anyone explain why $a^{b^c} = a^{(b^c)} \neq (a^b)^c = a^{(bc)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239825/can-anyone-explain-why-abc-abc-neq-abc-abc)  Also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027762/why-is-222n-not-equal-to-16n)

Comment: You can add the brackets whichever way you want, and that would determine the order. Until you add them, this expression is senseless.

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate, @RossMillikan. That question asks why the two expressions are different — a basic maths question that can be easily tested out on paper.

This question asks about the order of execution (which, yes, coincidentally is *mentioned* in that url). That won't show up on Google.

Comment: @qaisjp:  both of them explain the convention, which is that we evaluate from right to left, and the reason behind it.  That is what is asked here.

Comment: If you omit parenthesis then, your expression becomes open for interpretations. Software tools define their rules the way they like as long as it does not contradict with definitions. It is best to add parenthesis to eliminate any possible ambiguity, It is important to know that the sequence of operation, in absence of parenthesis depends on the operations involved.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).